# Conjugacy of Borel subgroups over arbitrary fields

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Let $k$ be a field and $G$ a connected semisimple algebraic group over $k$.

If $k$ is algebraically closed, then it is well known that all Borel subgroups of $G$ are conjugate by the action of $G(k)$. I would like to know whether this is also true over non-closed fields.

> > Are all Borel subgroups of $G$ over $k$ conjugate by the action of $G(k)$?

Recall that a Borel subgroup $B$ of $G$ over $k$ is a closed subgroup of $G$ over $k$ such that the base change of $B$ to the algebraic closure $\bar{k}$ is a Borel subgroup of $G \times_k \bar{k}$.

Of course Borel subgroups need not exist in general; when they do one says that $G$ is quasi-split. If $G$ is not quasi-split then the statement is vacuously true.

Comment: As you note, Borel subgroups over $k$ need not exist in general.   In fact they rarely exist over the typical fields people work with which are not algebraically closed: real, $p$-adic, number fields, etc.   But it's a standard fact that a connected semisimple group defined over a finite field (or more generally over a field of cohomological dimension 1) is quasi-split over that field.    Borel and Tits developed their more elaborate theory involving relative roots and $k$-parabolic subgroups to deal with the general ($k$-isotropic) case.

Comment: I have a similar question. Suppose that G / Zp is a split group. Is it true that in G all Borel subgroups are conjugate? (Zp being the p-adic integers)

Comment: @mnr It might be better to ask a separate question. In any case, have a look at Thm. 5.2.11 in http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/papers/luminysga3.pdf

Comment: @mnr Wait, actually, have a look at Prop. 6.2.11 (last sentence). That says that (G,T,B) is isom to (G,T,B') and that the isom can be given by conjugation with an element in G(S).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. This follows directly from Theorem 20.9 (i) in "Armand Borel, Linear Algebraic Groups, Second enlarged edition, 1991" which goes like this:

**Theorem**: Let $ G $ be a connected reductive group over a field $ k $. The minimal parabolic $k$-subgroups of $G$ are conjugate under $G(k)$.

Comment: Can you add the statement of the theorem (or a rough version) to your answer? Currently it's not clear from your answer what the answer to the question is.

Comment: Indeed. I've clarified my answer.

Comment: Great, thanks! I had tried looking in Borel's book but had missed this result.

Comment: Note that this basic conjugacy result is due to Borel and Tits: Thm. 4.13 in their foundational 1965 paper *Groupes reductifs*.   For online access see http://www.numdam.org/numdam-bin/item?id=PMIHES_1965__27__55_0